# How do I tell Photoshop to preserve the RGB color of fully-transparent pixels when exporting as PNG?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png

I'm having a problem with how Photoshop handles completely-transparent pixels when exporting as PNG, which is that the red, green, and blue color channels of any completely-transparent pixels are saved as 0 instead of the color that I define in Photoshop.

For example: I have a PSD file with a layer mask. Some colored portions of the image are made completely transparent by the layer mask, but I still want the original color channels to be written to the PNG file instead of just 0.

(Yes, the PNG format itself *does* contain RGB data even for fully-transparent pixels. This is a problem with Photoshop, not PNG.)

If you're wondering *why* having color data matters when a pixel is completely transparent, then here are a couple of use cases:

- The PNG is being sampled at a higher resolution than it is saved as and the sampled values are interpolated between neighboring pixels. This can result in a faint black "halo" around the image if the interpolation isn't weighted by transparency. (In my case, this up-sampling is being done on the GPU, which for performance reasons does not weigh by transparency.)
- The red, green, blue, and alpha channels in the PNG file are being used for purposes other than storing color information. (In my case, I use all four channels to store data needed for real-time lighting computations.)

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

I'm going to try to explain the problem I'm having with use of some visual aids. Showing transparent things is hard, but hopefully this makes my problem clearer:

I have a PSD file with one layer and a layer mask. The color layer looks like this:

[image]

Its layer mask looks like this:

[image]

If I export this PSD file as a PNG, I get this:

[image]

(The white regions are indeed transparent; they just look white against the white background.)

You may be wondering: What's the problem? That looks right! Well, the problem is with the color information stored in those transparent pixels. Using a tool to strip out the opacity data from the PNG while leaving the RGB intact, we can see the color information that Photoshop saves to the transparent pixels:

[image]

As you can see, Photoshop has replaced the color information in the transparent pixels with black. Whereas, with the opacity data removed from the PNG, I want it to look exactly like the original color layer:

[image]

Comment: Showing an example of what you are experiencing might be more helpful. Mainly because, there should not be any color information in the transparent portion of the PNG. How are you saving out the PNG? Are you using "Save for Web" and do you have the "transparency" checked?  I know it sounds basic but not sure how you are getting your results.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't post any example images because you can't actually *see* the issue (without loading the PNG in a paint program and turning off the transparency), since the issue is only with pixels that are completely transparent. I'll see if I can come up with a way to visualize what I'm talking about.

Comment: But when you say "there should not be any color information in the transparent portion of the PNG", I actually *want* there to be color information in the transparent portion of the PNG. I know that sounds wierd, but there are certain applications, such as the two I've mentioned above. (And yes, PNG totally supports color information in its transparent regions; I use it all the time in procedurally-generated PNGs. The issue is with how Photoshop saves transparent regions to PNGs.)

Comment: @ErickP Okay, I edited my post with visual examples.

Comment: 100% transparency is just that. There is *no* rgb data to be included to begin with. What you are asking for isn't supported by Photoshop AFAIK, as there is no RGB value to put into a fully transparent pixel.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but perhaps the RGBA PNG format would be what you need? (Just a wild guess, but maybe PS isn't actually saving the alpha mask data and is just 'flattening' the mask upon export leading to the results you see) http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter08.html#png.ch08.div.5.7 Maybe there's a 3rd party plugin for PS that would allow for that?

Comment: @DA01 Photoshop already natively supports RGBA PNG (that's the format it uses when saving a PNG with transparency). In the context of PNGs, transparency=alpha.

But yeah, an acceptable and much-appreciated solution would be a plugin which could save RGBA PNG with my color info intact. I've searched for one but haven't found one yet.

Comment: I'm sorry but wouldn't that all be dependant on the application/use you are importing this PNG in to? What are you trying to do with this PNG? What is the application for the PNG? For example, if for some reason you are importing that PNG into an App that for some bizarre reason doesn't support the "transparency" of that PNG then you might be out of luck. But I personally haven't run into that issue. Either the App accepts the PNG or it doesn't.

Comment: @WaltD seems that this is perhaps a bug in PS, eh?

Comment: @ErickP It's a game which up-scales the image on the GPU. When upscaled, the color values of transparent pixels will *bleed* into neighboring pixels. (This has to do with how the GPU interpolates between pixels and the annoying fact that it ignores transparency when interpolating color values.) Since Photoshop saves black to transparent pixels, black colors get bled into the surrounding pixels. This is a *very* common problem in game development, and so I'm pretty surprised that I haven't yet found a way or plugin to make Photoshop save the correct color values for transparent pixels.

Comment: @DA01 I don't think it's a bug as much as it's an optimzation that Photoshop does (PNGs with uniform colors take less disk space) that is breaking my particular use case.

Comment: @Walt D  Game development is definitely not in my wheel house but from what I gather this can be an issue with both the GPU and PNG. Unless all GPU's are created equal, then a so-called plugin might have to be written specifically for each one (GPU) in order for the PNG to be read correctly.  Again, not an expert but just a guess. Wish I could help further.

Comment: @ErickP Thanks for trying to help, I really appreciate it. :)  Thankfully, GPUs are pretty standard these days, and this kind of upscaling (known as bilinear interpolation) works exactly the same across all of them, so whatever solution I do eventually find *should* work universally.

Comment: I understand exactly what the OP is trying to do, and Photoshop should definitely have an option to preserve this information. In my case, I am exporting roughness, metallic, emissive, and ambient occlusion into the 4 channels of the PNG, and anywhere where the ambient occlusion is black, I lose all other data because of this "optimization". Since Substance Painter has terrible resizing quality, I have to use Photoshop to do the resizing, but then this happens. It's like falling and trying to catch yourself, but then grabbing onto a sharp knife. Hopefully SuperPNG works to correct this.Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found a solution! The [SuperPNG](http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/) plugin will preserve the RGB values for transparent pixels as long as you leave the "Clean Transparent" option unchecked.

Comment: I'm curious if there is a Photoshop CC equivalent to SuperPNG?

Comment: It is worth noting that SuperPNG seems to work fine with Photoshop CC.

Comment: For the record, newer versions of Photoshop do not seem to automatically destroy transparent color data when saving. However, far worse, newer versions of photoshop destroy color data when the image is manipulated or modified, such as painting or resizing. Because of this, SuperPNG will not resolve the issue if you are doing any type of modification inside Photoshop. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a solution for this.

Comment: Sorry, have to make a correction. Apparently I do not know how to use SuperPNG correctly. At first glance, I thought it was an export tool only, but if you hold shift while opening PNG files, it will open a dialog to allow you to store alpha as a separate channel while editing in Photoshop. As long as the document is edited in this way, the color data should be preserved. Thanks a bunch to Walt D for the solution.